# Aligning list elements Sagemath

Tags: list, formatting, alignment, decimal, sage

I have a huge list with hundreds of thousands of numbers. The list is badly formatted when produced by sagemath, but i must have it in the kind of formatting shown below to "feed" it to another function. Here is sample of the well formatted list:

```
           C=[
           (  7.850629, 25.421135, 22.162571),
           ( 37.706629, 28.421472,  0.229876),
           ( 37.560629, 21.421809, 18.320977),
           ( 39.238629, 26.422147, 18.442572),
           ( 35.087169,  0.419785, 15.055789),
           ]
```

As you can see, all elements are aligned to the right as well as based on the precision and decimal place. So my question is this: **How can i convert the badly formatted list (example shown below) to the well formatted above**

```
    B=[(37.074945, 22.414327,
9.756234), (37.074945, 22.414665,
1.669214), (37.074945, 22.415002,
8.571376), (37.074945, 22.41534,
1.294731), (37.074945, 22.415677,
5.753062), (37.074945, 22.416014,
7.519850)]
```

(If i could describe it even a bit more, i would say that if my list is thought of as a matrix, then it would have tenths of thousands of rows and three columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sage doesn't have good alignment functions built-in. If you're willing to think of your list as a matrix, you can do

```
sage: matrix(B)
[37.0749450000000 22.4143270000000 9.75623400000000]
[37.0749450000000 22.4146650000000 1.66921400000000]
[37.0749450000000 22.4150020000000 8.57137600000000]
[37.0749450000000 22.4153400000000 1.29473100000000]
[37.0749450000000 22.4156770000000 5.75306200000000]
[37.0749450000000 22.4160140000000 7.51985000000000]
```

It's missing the commas and other syntactical pieces, but it's aligned properly. If you're willing to work with html output, you can do `html.table(B)`. In the future (see [this possible future enhancement](http://trac.sagemath.org/sage_trac/ticket/13131)) there ought to be a good "table" function for nice displays like this in general.

Comment: The problem is that the example data was not good ,well, for an example. Matrix won't align the elements according to decimal place  C=[(37.074945, 22.414327,
9.756234), (37.074945, 22.414665,
1.669214), (37.074945, 22.415002,
8.571376), (37.074945, 22.41534,
18.294731), (37.074945, 22.415677,
5.753062), (37.074945, 22.416014,
17.519850)]
you see this by trying out with this one. Nevertheless i accomplished my current task because of your help.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that's a general Python question. Given the `C` in your comment, the following work. The `"%9.5f"` is the key insight:

```
for l in C:
    print "(%s)," % ', '.join("%9.5f"%i for i in l)
   ....:     
( 37.07494,  22.41433,   9.75623),
( 37.07494,  22.41466,   1.66921),
( 37.07494,  22.41500,   8.57138),
( 37.07494,  22.41534,  18.29473),
( 37.07494,  22.41568,   5.75306),
( 37.07494,  22.41601,  17.51985),
```